# single Rotation gesture event is not working?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I am using following code

```
recognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotationFrom:)];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
 [recognizer release];
```

but when i  do single finger rotation event. the function handleRotationFrom  is not called? any help please?I have added delegate method also in my UIView..any help please?

Answer (score 4):

A rotation gesture always involves two touches. If you want to test it in iphone simulator hold down option key while clicking.